# Is my hard drive in the process of becoming faulty?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, chkdsk

There was no lead up symptoms to what I'm currently going through with my home machine. What happened was;

Casual non intensive usage on the machine, then everything locked up and would not resume after approximately 10 minutes of waiting. So I had to perform a hard reset by hitting the button on my tower.

Happy feelings that the restart was going to resolve the unexpected lock up, but after booking past POST  and hitting the windows start up screen. Which hanged for approximately 10/15 minutes and would not load. Unsatisfied with the time. I hit the hard restart again to attempt to boot into last known good configuration.

This resulted in the same effect of a hanging load screen. I then attempted to boot into safe mode, which froze on a few drivers. Restarting (again hard) I boot into recovery and use command prompt to change the driver names most of which included drivers from the AVG package.

After doing this, I restart the machine to attempt safe mode. This time freezing at classpnp.sys,  back to recovery to change the name (not remove) which resulted in blue screen. Back into recovery to change the file name back to the original state. Then after yet another restart I booted into safe mode which took about 20 minutes to load. I perform a sfc /scannow which complete did find some files to log (currently cannot access the machine to paste)
After this, I restart and attempt to boot into windows. After hitting the login screen it took roughly 10 minutes to get to the login screen. I login and everything runs normal. Happy that I sorted it

On the next start up (today), same problem arises.everything locks up so I have to hard restart. Windows login hangs yet again, this time I wait it out. It requests a CHKDSK so I let it run. Now currently 10 hours in, it's on step 3/3 and 64% (at time of this post).

Could this be that my drive is in the process of becoming faulty

[image]

Comment: Still at 64% processing on average 20 - 30 files every ~2 seconds

Comment: `I then attempted to boot into safe mode, which froze on a few drivers. Restarting (again hard) I boot into recovery and use command prompt to change the driver names most of which included drivers from the AVG package.`  My face literally palmed there... so thanks for that.  But the actual source of your problem seems to be that you got impatient and started screwing with things you didn't understand.  You probably just need to format the drive, reinstall Windows, and do it better next time.  On the topic of doing it better, ditch AVG and use MS Security Essentials.

Comment: @hopelessN00b I have had AVG on my machine for over a year, never encountered these problems previously.. Being safemode froze when loading the drivers at all. Possibly a coincidence that it stuck on them. Sys files, formatting the drive is always a final resort. I considered failure/fault because how sudden this has occurred. As of posting this I have logged into my machine and will backup as advised. Order a new drive as indirectly advised twice, I'm not discrediting you. Just find it hard to believe an installation causing no conflict for over a year suddenly causes system lockups

Comment: Well, I'm assuming you didn't go around renaming drivers before either.  I'm not saying it isn't a drive going bad... it very well could be... I'm just saying that it could just as easily be a result of messing around with low-level system driver files as well.  And for future reference, Windows hanging at the Windows logo for 10 or 15 minutes isn't always an indication of a problem.  Happens frequently when processing a lot of updates, or when an applied update goes wrong and has to be removed.  For next time, I'd advise a little more patience before attacking those driver files.

Comment: @HopelessN00b windows update is turned off on this machine, so I can rule that one out, with renaming the driver names. The choice to do so was made when booting into safemode was halted by the driver names. Only issued 'ren old.sys old.sys.old'  all are still to be reverted back. Whilst logged in. Performance is extremely sluggish will try to run a perfmon to check I/O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it could.

Some years ago, I had roughly similar behaviour on an Win-XP machine.
There were no errors, but within a few weeks, boot time growed and growed – without doing heavy (de)installing. When it took more than five minutes to boot up, I decided to put the machine to delivery status. So I updated my backup and made an image of boot partition – there were neither errors during reading the whole disk nor unusual slow data rate (not measured, just by perception).

After fresh installation of XP – even without installed updates – it took more than – well, guess,… five minutes to boot.

Warranty was still valid, so I returned the whole computer – and it came back with 80 GB instead of previous 60 GB. I put back the image, and it booted like a charm in about half a minute…

Back to your computer…

I'd boot with a GNU/Linux live medium and get **smartmontools**.
Then open a command line window (terminal window) and retrieve smart data.
I couldn't memorise the exact way how to do. The command is called **smartctl,** but look for any parameters. I think I'm able to help, if you got further questions (but not today).

Good luck – Peter

Comment: Unfortunately I do not want to mess more data up if my data has started to mess up due to this. I think I'm going to wait out the,remaining time for this CHKDSK to finish. Luckily  I have a 1TB. External. Only complication is that I do not have a spare replacement drive to hand. The drive I got next to me has been sitting on the carpet for a prolonged period of time, ESD possibility is quite high, so will have to backup and order a replacement

Comment: ESD is nothing that accumulates up. If ESD kills at all, it wont kill the disk, merely the controller. If it kills, it kills in a single, short attack. It doesn't kill stored data.

Comment: Though, if my calculations are correct. Processing 20 files minimum every 2 seconds currently at 432000 of 854528 it'll take approx 10 - 11 hours to complete & being on a carpet could have damaged it none the less, no?

Comment: If there are data that is not backed up. I'd stop _any_ access _immediately_ – even CHKDSK. If it fails to be stopped, consider to powercycle. Albeit this stresses the unload mechanism.

Comment: Why do you think ESD is an issue? Just because it is a carpet, where the drive is put?

Comment: The old drive yeah. Just a concern that it's been left on a surface known to create electro static, face down with the board on the surface

Comment: Turns out the drive is becoming faulty. Performance with I/O is degrading, I've took your advice and booted to a Live Linux disk to back up my files, a new hard drive has been ordered

Comment: Then again. I'm currently transferring the final folder of a backup, 7GB I'm getting a transfer rate from (faulting) drive to an external at an average 20 - 25mb/sec. Actual usage of the drive reaches no where near that and is degrading when running windows from said drive

Comment: smartmontools also has a windows port - I use it with gsmartcontrol.

Answer (score 1):

First, the comments about static ... static electricity builds with motion, so the drive sitting there won't do anything aside from making it a bit warmer. Most likely, you have bad blocks on the disk and it's heading out the door. Make an immediate backup of what you can and replace. It's really the only way. There's no sense testing the drive as its poor performance is a clear indicator of impending failure and further tests will only stress the drive further.